# How to load a basic view using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a view called index.php from my controller, which is called anish.php. Here is what I have so far for my controller:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Anish extends Public_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
// Load the required classes
$this->load->model('anish_m');
$this->lang->load('anish');

$this->template
  ->append_css('module::anish.css')
  ->append_js('module::anish.js');
}
public function index()
{
$this->template
  ->set('anish')
  ->build('index');
}
}
```

And this is what I have in my index.php:

#### Hello world

I appreciate anyone's help. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is, exactly. But to load a view (say index.php), from any method of your controller, you call:

```
$this->load->view('index');
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load your index.php view in the index function do something like

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');//index is the name of the view file minus the .php extension
}
```

If you want to pass any data to your view then do it using the second parameter.  For example

```
public function index()
{
    $aData['hello'] = 'Hello World!';
    $this->load->view('index', $aData);//In the view you would then do <?php echo $hello; ?>
}
```

When you call a view it echo's it out immediately.  If you want to save the contents of the view to a variable instead you would pass TRUE as the third parameter

```
public function index()
{
    $aData['hello'] = 'Hello World!';
    $this->load->view('index', $aData, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: For the URL, it is case-sensitive to the module. I simply had to capitalize the first letter. Thank you all for your help.